# kendoui grid custom numeric format pattern

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I'd like to format a numeric columns as follow: `"23400,34"`

> 1) "," as decimal separator (if decimal is present).
>
> 2) no thousands separator.

I used this pattern `"{0:#,##}"`

This seems applyes `","` as thousands separator

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `replace` function, like so:

```
kendo.format("{0:0.00}", value).replace(".", ",")
```